# Program terminates even after exception handling

Tags: c++

I have a try catch block, as far as I know if an exception is throw I handle it in catch block and then program continues to work which is not happening in my case.

**main.cpp inside main function**

```
    const Matrix<int, 3, 2> m1; // Creates 3*2 matrix, with all the default elements set to 0;
    Matrix<int, 3, 3> m2(4); // Creates 3*3 matrix, with the default elements equals to 4;
    const Matrix<int, 3, 3> m3 = m2; // C-py constructor may take O(MN) and not O(1).
    try
    {
        cout << m2 + m3 << endl;
        cout << m3 * m1 << endl; // You can choose the format of matrix printing;
        cout << m1 * m2;         // This should throw an exception
    }
    catch (const Matrix<int, 3, 2>::IllegalOperation &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    cout << m2[0][0] << " " << m2[1][0] << endl; // Should print "13 4"
```

**Header file from where everything is imported from**

```
template <class T, int M, int N>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T mat[M][N];
    int rows = M;
    int cols = N;
```

**Edit as per johns solution**
Error class definition.

```
// Error class
    class IllegalOperation : public std::exception
    {
    public:
        IllegalOperation(const char *msg) _msg(msg){};
        virtual const char *what() const throw() { return _msg.c_str(); };

    private:
        std::string _msg;
    };
```

I am getting errors here.

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:
matrix.h:16:41: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   16 |         IllegalOperation(const char *msg) _msg(msg){};
      |                                         ^
      |                                          ;
matrix.h:16:48: error: ‘msg’ has not been declared
   16 |         IllegalOperation(const char *msg) _msg(msg){};
      |                                                ^~~
matrix.h:16:43: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘_msg’ with no type [-fpermissive]
   16 |         IllegalOperation(const char *msg) _msg(msg){};
      |                                           ^~~~
matrix.h:20:21: error: ‘std::string Matrix<T, M, N>::IllegalOperation::_msg’ conflicts with a previous declaration
   20 |         std::string _msg;
      |                     ^~~~
matrix.h:16:43: note: previous declaration ‘int Matrix<T, M, N>::IllegalOperation::_msg(int)’
   16 |         IllegalOperation(const char *msg) _msg(msg){};
      |                                           ^~~~
matrix.h: In member function ‘int Matrix<T, M, N>::IllegalOperation::_msg(int)’:
matrix.h:16:53: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   16 |         IllegalOperation(const char *msg) _msg(msg){};
      |                                                     ^
matrix.h: In member function ‘virtual const char* Matrix<T, M, N>::IllegalOperation::what() const’:
matrix.h:17:59: error: invalid use of member function ‘int Matrix<T, M, N>::IllegalOperation::_msg(int)’ (did you forget the ‘()’ ?)
   17 |         virtual const char *what() const throw() { return _msg.c_str(); };
      |                                                           ^~~~
matrix.h:17:64: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘c_str’
   17 |         virtual const char *what() const throw() { return _msg.c_str(); };
      |                                                                ^~~~~
matrix.h:17:64: error: there are no arguments to ‘c_str’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘c_str’ must be available [-fpermissive]
matrix.h:17:64: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
matrix.h: In instantiation of ‘const char* Matrix<T, M, N>::IllegalOperation::what() const [with T = int; int M = 3; int N = 2]’:
main.cpp:35:23:   required from here
matrix.h:17:69: error: ‘c_str’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘wcsstr’?
   17 |         virtual const char *what() const throw() { return _msg.c_str(); };
      |                                                                ~~~~~^~
      |                                                                wcsstr
matrix.h: In instantiation of ‘const char* Matrix<T, M, N>::IllegalOperation::what() const [with T = int; int M = 3; int N = 3]’:
matrix.h:17:29:   required from here
matrix.h:17:69: error: ‘c_str’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘wcsstr’?
   17 |         virtual const char *what() const throw() { return _msg.c_str(); };
      |                                                                ~~~~~^~
      |                                                                wcsstr
```

**Continuation of the header file**

```
    // constructor
    Matrix(int v = 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                mat[i][j] = v;
        }
    }

    // () overloading
    T &operator()(int i, int j)
    {
        return mat[i][j];
    };

    const T &operator()(int i, int j) const
    {
        return mat[i][j];
    };

    // [] overloading
    T *operator[](int index)
    {
        return mat[index];
    };
    const T *operator[](int index) const
    {
        return mat[index];
    };

    // << overloading
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Matrix<T, M, N> &L)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                os << L.mat[i][j] << " ";
            os << "\n";
        }
        return os;
    };

    template <class T1, int M1, int N1>
    Matrix<T, M, N1> operator*(Matrix<T1, M1, N1> const &other);
    template <class T1, int M1, int N1>
    const Matrix<T, M, N1> operator*(Matrix<T1, M1, N1> const &other) const;
    Matrix<T, M, N> operator+(Matrix<T, M, N> const &other);

    friend T min(Matrix obj)
    {
        T result = obj.mat[0][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                if (result < obj.mat[i][j])
                    result = obj.mat[i][j];
        }
        return result;
    };

    long double avg() const
    {
        long double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                if (result < mat[i][j])
                    result = result + mat[i][j];
        }
        return result / (M * N);
    }
};

template <class T, int M, int N>
Matrix<T, M, N> Matrix<T, M, N>::operator+(Matrix const &other)
{
    if ((this->rows == other.rows) && (this->cols == other.cols))
    {
        Matrix<T, M, N> resultantMatrix;

        for (auto i = 0; i < this->rows; i++)
        {
            for (auto j = 0; j < this->cols; j++)
            {
                auto &valueFirst = this->mat[i][j];
                auto &valueSecond = other.mat[i][j];

                // if ((additionOverflow(valueFirst, valueSecond)) || (additionUnderflow(valueFirst, valueSecond)))
                //     throw std::out_of_range("Resultant value of matrix is out of range");
                // else
                resultantMatrix(i, j) = valueFirst + valueSecond;
            }
        }
        return resultantMatrix;
    }
    else
        throw("Matrices cannot be added, sizes do not match");
}

template <class T, int M, int N>
template <class T1, int M1, int N1>
Matrix<T, M, N1> Matrix<T, M, N>::operator*(Matrix<T1, M1, N1> const &other)
{
    std::cout << M << " " << N1;
    if (N == M1)
    {
        Matrix<T, M, N1> resultantMatrix;

        for (auto i = 0; i < this->rows; i++)
        {
            for (auto j = 0; j < this->cols; j++)
            {
                for (auto k = 0; k < this->cols; k++)
                {
                    auto &valueFirst = this->mat[i][k];
                    auto &valueSecond = other(k, j);

                    // if ((additionOverflow(valueFirst, valueSecond)) || (additionUnderflow(valueFirst, valueSecond)))
                    //     throw std::out_of_range("Resultant value of matrix is out of range");
                    // else
                    resultantMatrix(i, j) += valueFirst * valueSecond;
                }
            }
        }
        return resultantMatrix;
    }
    else
        throw("Matrices cannot be added, sizes do not match");
}

template <class T, int M, int N>
template <class T1, int M1, int N1>
Matrix<T, M, N1> const Matrix<T, M, N>::operator*(Matrix<T1, M1, N1> const &other) const
{
    if (N == M1)
    {
        Matrix<T, M, N1> resultantMatrix;

        for (auto i = 0; i < this->rows; i++)
        {
            for (auto j = 0; j < this->cols; j++)
            {
                for (auto k = 0; k < this->cols; k++)
                {
                    auto &valueFirst = this->mat[i][k];
                    auto &valueSecond = other(k, j);

                    // if ((additionOverflow(valueFirst, valueSecond)) || (additionUnderflow(valueFirst, valueSecond)))
                    //     throw std::out_of_range("Resultant value of matrix is out of range");
                    // else
                    resultantMatrix(i, j) += valueFirst * valueSecond;
                }
            }
        }
        return resultantMatrix;
    }
    else
        throw("Matrices cannot be added, sizes do not match");
}
```

**Output at the end**

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why is the core getting dumped? I have thrown an error, I have handled it. What am I missing?
Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You are throwing a string literal, not a `IllegalOperation` which your `catch` handler expects. The types must match (up to inheritance).

Comment: `throw("Matrices cannot be added, sizes do not match");` is not the same as `throw SomeException("message");`

Comment: You have no constructor for `IllegalOperation` either - consider deriving it from something like [`std::logic_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error).

Comment: Brett Hale, aren't there default constructors in class if there none defined?

Comment: @VanWilder Yes, but it seems that you want to pass a message to the constructor.

Comment: @user17732522, How will I even throw an IllegalOperation since it is a member of Matrix class? Something like `throw Matrix<int, 3,2>::IllegalOperation("error")`?

Comment: @VanWilder I wouldn't make it a member of the Matrix class in the first place. There doesn't seem to be any good reason to have a different `IllegalOperation` type for each class template specialization. Which of the two would you even choose for a binary operation on two different specializations?

Comment: Yes, like that, but you didn't specify a constructor that this could use. (And there is of course no reason to be using that `Matrix` specialization in particular, see my previous comment.)

Comment: The presence or absence of default constructors in the class are irrelevant.     The statement `throw("Matrices cannot be added, sizes do not match")` throws a string literal.   There is no information in that statement that requires an instance of `Matrix<int, 3, 2>::IllegalOperation` to be constructed in order to be thrown.  The type of a string literal is different from `Matrix<int, 3, 2>::IllegalOperation` (which your code tries to catch) but the types don't match, so the exception is not caught.

Comment: And in a wider view of what you are trying to do: This is not a case where you should be using exceptions. Exceptions are used for exceptional conditions which can happen at runtime. But here you are only verifying that template parameters (which are completely determined at compile-time) satisfy some condition. If that condition is not satisfied you shouldn't wait until runtime to throw an exception. You can just ask the compiler to tell you immediately, e.g. with `static_assert(N == M1);`.

Comment: @user17732522 This is a task I was given, I can't change `main.cpp` hence I have to create a header file according to it. Which in this case happens to be a part of Matrix class. Now, I have no idea how a constructor would look like here.

Comment: And going even one step further, if you want to always be the same, then you can just reuse them, just replace `M1` with `N` everywhere and remove `M1` from the template parameter list.

Comment: @VanWilder Then it is a badly designed task.

Comment: Just publicly inherit from `std::logic_error` as mentioned above and add `using std::logic_error::logic_error;` as the only member declaration of the class, you don't need to add anything else.

Comment: Ahah, I wish I could say that to my professor. @user17732522

Comment: ```class IllegalOperation : public std::logic_error
    {
    public:
        virtual const char *what() const throw() { return "message"; }
    };```
Something like this?

Comment: @VanWilder `struct IllegalOperation : std::logic_error { using std::logic_error::logic_error; };`

Comment: Your first error appears to possibly derive from your initializer list missing a `:`. `IllegalOperation(const char *msg) _msg(msg){};` -> `IllegalOperation(const char *msg) : _msg(msg){};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First move the exception class outside of the matrix class

```
template <class T, int M, int N>
class Matrix
{
};

class IllegalOperation
{
};
```

The way you have it now, every different kind of matrix class throws a different kind of exception. That's going to make using the exception class really difficult..

Make the same change to your catch block (and make it catch a `const` reference)

```
catch (const IllegalOperation &e)
```

Add constructor etc. to your exception class, (exception classes are no different from any other class, they need constructors and methods and members). Although not completely necessary, it's reasonable to derive the exception class from `std::exception` as I've done below. If you haven't done this already you'll need to add the header for `std::exception`

```
#include <exception>

...

class IllegalOperation : public std::exception
{
public:
    IllegalOperation(const char* msg) : _msg(msg) {}
    virtual const char *what() const { return _msg.c_str(); }
private:
    std::string _msg;
};
```

Finally throw your exception class, not a string.

```
throw IllegalOperation("Matrices cannot be added, sizes do not match");
```

Comment: I can't change my catch block unfortunately.  Can I do this while keeping it a member of Matrix class? Reading the comments would help you understand my issue.

Comment: Beware though that this implementation of the exception is not generally safe. Its copy-construction can throw which, if that happens from an invocation of the exception handling mechanism, will cause a call to `std::terminate` as well. (For a school assignment probably no one cares about that though and even in practice that is an edge case that one might or might not care about.)

Comment: @user17732522 I agree, but I'm trying to keep things simple.

Comment: @VanWilder That's crazy, I think your teacher doesn't understand C++ programming very well. But yes you can make all the changes except the two about moving the exception class outside of the matrix class.

Comment: I am trying my best to understand how all of this working, I appreciate you guys helping. Thank you so much, I will try and see how it goes!

Comment: @VanWilder I also just realize that you are using `throw()` in the declaration of `what`. This is called a _dynamic exception specification_ and they have been deprecated since C++11 and have been removed completely from the language since C++17. You shouldn't use them at all. It should now be `noexcept` instead.

Comment: One thing to understand is that there really is no such thing as an *exception class*, there are just classes which you happen to throw as exceptions. So all the usual rules about classes also apply to exception classes. As you have found out you can throw absolutely anything, including strings, which is why when you use `throw` you have to say exactly which type of object you are throwing.

Comment: @user17732522 I've removed that from my code (which I'd just cut and paste from the OP code without noticing it).

Comment: @user17732522, So instead of `throw("message")`, I do `noexcept("message")`?

Comment: @john Yes, just wanted to let you know as well in one comment.

Comment: @VanWilder No you do `throw IllegalOperation("Matrices cannot be added, sizes do not match");` as I explained above.

Comment: @VanWilder No, I am talking specifically about `throw()` after `virtual const char *what() const`. You can also just remove it instead of replacing it, as this answer now does.

Comment: I implemented this and updated my answer, I am getting different errors now. Can you have a look?

Comment: @VanWilder Yes my fault, correct code is `IllegalOperation(const char *msg) : _msg(msg) {}` see the extra `:` (but the extra `;` that you added is incorrect.

Comment: @VanWilder I see the same error in various places in your code. You do not need `};` at the end of a function, just `}`. Many compilers will let you get away with this, but it is an error.

Comment: Understood, can you explain a little bit about what's happening in the constructor?

Comment: The constructor is taking `const char*` (i.e. a C style string) and using it to construct a `std::string` called `_msg`. It's called an *initialiser list*, have you not seen it before? It's a normal C++ technique (and nothing specifically to do with exceptions)

Comment: @john An optional `;` after a function definition in a class is specifically allowed by the language grammar and at namespace scope it also works as an _emtpy-declaration_. The language would actually be a bit less convoluted if we would just always add a semicolon by convention (but of course that's not how it is).

Comment: @user17732522 Interesting. Has it always been so? I'm pretty sure I've worked with a compiler in the past which objected. It grates whenever I see it though.

Comment: @john The (single) optional one in a class definition has always been allowed in ISO C++, but at namespace scope it is only allowed since C++11 (but as many as you want; linters are going to complain though).

Comment: @user17732522 The Cppreference page about C++ declarations has a table of [defect reports](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations#Defect_reports) claiming that [CWG 569](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/569.html) was applied retroactively to C++98. Are you saying that the so-called _empty declaration_ itself was introduced only since C++11?

Comment: @heapunderrun I often have a hard time figuring out which issue resolutions are considered DRs against previous revisions and which revisions. My understanding is that the problem is that this isn't actually a formal ISO process, which only allows publication of a new standard revision or a Technical Corrigendum. ISO also considers previous revisions of the standard to be withdrawn. But generally I would expect cppreference to be trustworthy on how DRs are intended to apply. However, in this case both GCC and Clang consider it to not apply before C++11: https://godbolt.org/z/3q6q4jev8

Answer (score 2):

You have two key problems overall. First, you should move the exception type (ie. class) out of the Matrix's definition and make it an independent type. This is because the exception is logically from the matrix and just a means to correctly handle errors, thus not required to construct a valid matrix.

```cpp
class IllegalOperation 
{ /* Definition goes here */};

template<typename T, int M, int N>
class Matrix
{ /* Definition goes here */ };
```

The second problem is that when you are throwing the exceptions, you are throwing a them with a `const char*`, ie. a string literal, which is not what you `catch` expression is expecting, thus because the an exception is thrown but not caught, the program terminates.
In order to throw the exception that you are expecting you need to;

1. (i) construct a more rigorous exception type that has a constructor that takes a string literal or a std::string (or an other string type); (ii) or inherit from one of the standard libraries exceptions, giving you access to these constructors as they are already defined. @Brett Hale suggested [`std::logic_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) which is a great place to start. As it carries the semantic value that the error is a logical error. [`std::invalid_argument`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) is also a good choice that is a little more specific (and derived from `std::logic_error` itself). Exceptions are found in the stdexcept header. If you do derive from a standard exception, you will still need to create a constructor but you can just call the parent types constructor within your constructor.

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>

/* ... */

class IllegelOperation : public std::logic_error 
{
    IllegelOperation(const std::string& s_error)
    : std::logic_error(s_error.c_str())
    { }

    /// Note: no need for IllegelOperation::what() as std::logic_error handles that
};
```

2. Second, where the exceptions are being thrown, you need to throw the actual exception you want. An example throw expression would be:

```cpp
throw IllegelOperation("message");
```

This means that your catch expression should look like:

```cpp
catch (const IllegelOperation& e)
{ /* handle error */ }
```

Hopefully this helps.